# Angular JS Nested Services Unit Testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, ecmascript-6

I spent all afternoon trying to write a Unit Test for a service that is working as expected, without success. The problem comes from the dependencies injected, because I have another service that is passing the unit tests (it doesn't have dependencies).

The service is this

```js
import angular from 'angular';

export class IPMAService {
  /*@ngInject*/
  constructor($http, localStorageService, appConfig, locationStorageKey) {
    debugger;
    this.$http = $http;
    this.localStorage = localStorageService;
    this.appConfig = appConfig;
    this.locationStorageKey = locationStorageKey;
    if (Object.keys(this.localStorage.get(locationStorageKey)).length < 1) {
      console.log("IPMAService - Initialization (locations not present in local storage)");
      this._getLocationsFromService();
    }
  }

  getLocations() {
    console.log("IPMAService - Get Locations");   
    var locations = this.localStorage.get(this.locationStorageKey);
    if(!locations){
      return this._getLocationsFromService();
    }
    return locations;
  };

  _getLocationsFromService(){
      var _self = this;
      this.$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: this.appConfig.ipmaWebServices.locations
      }).then((response) => {
        _self.localStorage.set(_self.locationStorageKey, response.data);
        console.log("IPMAService - Saved locations.json to local storage with key: " + _self.locationStorageKey);
        return response;
      })
      .catch((response) => {
        console.log("IPMAService - Erro no acesso à api do IPMA: " + _self.appConfig.ipmaWebServices.locations);
      })
  }
}

export default angular.module('services.ipmaService', [])
  .service('ipmaService', IPMAService)
  .name;
```

I read a lot about Unit Tests and I can't seem to get it to work. This was my last attempt (not even a basic .toBeDefined(), given that it crashes in the inject function: "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"):

```js
'use strict';

import serviceModule from './IPMAService.service';
import LocalStorageModule from 'angular-local-storage';
import constantsModule from '../../app/app.constants';

describe('Service: IPMAService', function () {
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module(serviceModule));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module(LocalStorageModule));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module(constantsModule));

    var localStorageService2, service, httpBackend, ipmawebservices, locationStoreKey2;

    beforeEach(inject(function (ipmaService, _$http_, localStorageService, appConfig, locationStoreKey) {
        service = ipmaService;
        httpBackend = _$http_;
        localStorageService2 = localStorageService;
        ipmawebservices = appConfig;
        locationStoreKey2 = locationStorageKey;

    }));

    it ('should be loaded', function() {
        expect(service).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Also...after I get this basic test to pass/work, I would like to know how can I, for example, test the **getLocations** method since it depends on the **_getLocationsFromService** method and **localStorage** (I think I have to use jasmine's SpyOn, but a little help would be great).

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

This was my final solution mixing the accepted answer and some more research. Hope it helps someone in the future who's desperate about Unit Tests.

*NOTE*: I removed the locationStorageKey dependency from the service

```js
'use strict';

import serviceModule, { IPMAService } from './IPMAService.service';
import LocalStorageModule from 'angular-local-storage';
import constantsModule from '../../app/app.constants';

describe('Service: IPMAService', function () {
    var mockDependency, appConfigDependency, service,
    locationsObject = [{ local: "Lisboa", latitude: 33, longitude: 10 },{ local: "Porto", latitude: 36, longitude: 9 }];
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module(serviceModule));

    beforeEach(function () {

        mockDependency = {
            get: function () {
                return locationsObject;
            }
        };

        appConfigDependency = {

        };

        angular.mock.module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('localStorageService', mockDependency);
        });

        angular.mock.module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.constant('appConfig', appConfigDependency);
        });

    }); 

    beforeEach(() => {
        spyOn(IPMAService.prototype, '_getLocationsFromService').and.returnValue(locationsObject);
    });

    it('should return location object', inject(function (ipmaService) {
        expect(ipmaService.getLocations()).toBe(locationsObject);
    }));


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question contains a catch. Nested services shouldn't be tested. Unit testing is about testing a unit, one at a time. One service (`ipmaService`) is tested, the others are mocked.

This list

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module(serviceModule));
beforeEach(angular.mock.module(LocalStorageModule));
beforeEach(angular.mock.module(constantsModule));
```

should become

```
var localStorageServiceMock = { get: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(...) };

beforeEach(angular.mock.module(serviceModule, {
  localStorageService: localStorageServiceMock,
  appConfig: ...,
  locationStorageKey: ...
}));
```

Fortunately, we have a separate class export with ES6 modules alongside with `default`:

```
import serviceModule, { IPMAService } from './IPMAService.service';
```

This gives us the opportunity to set up spies on class prototype methods before the service is instantiated with `inject`:

```
beforeEach(() => {
 spyOn(IPMAService.prototype, '_getLocationsFromService').and.callThrough();
});
...
expect(service._getLocationsFromService).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Alternatively, the method can be mocked in some service specs to improve granularity and focus on tested methods.

Spying on service's own method in constructor isn't a big deal but it adds the strength to specs.

Comment: I'll give it a try first thing in the morning, thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: I ended up mixing your answer with some others I saw, and I edited my post with my solution. Thank you for the help :)